# Backbone.Marionette vs Backbone-Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm new to Backbone and trying to decide how to approach development.

At the moment I'm wondering when people would use backbone.marionette over backbone-boilerplate?

From what I can tell Marionette is a lot more prescriptive, but is this the way that most people approach development here?

Comment: I would change this question to Marionette vs LayoutManager or something like that...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Marionette automates a lot of housekeeping work with respect to views that I believe Backbone should've included in the first place. Marionette is actively maintained and found it to be extremely useful and flexible for my project.

backbone-boilerplate, from what I see, is more of a way to organize your code into modules but doesn't touch Backbone views.

You should be able to use boilerplate for code organization, and Marionette for more-easily-manageable views. I believe they address complementing issues.

Marionette recently added an AMD version so it is now compatible with RequireJS out of the box.

Comment: I would also say that "Marionette vs Boilerplate" is the wrong thought process. They aren't in competition. They solve different problems and can be used together.

Comment: Thanks that what I wanted to know and I wasn't 100% clear on.

Comment: right...done the same use both boilerplate and marionette in one project -> added a project template for myself but feel free to use it https://github.com/jamuhl/bmq-tmpl