# Marionette.js compared to Chaplin.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette, chaplinjs

I currently in the process of concepting a large single page web application.
There will be a lot of components, so a separation of concerns is important to me. The Server is basically a REST-Server with some sugar, like sending Template Code to the client.

So I need to decide which MVC Framework I want to use client side.

I really like backbone.js so I want to have a big Framework relying on it.

What I came over is Marionette.js and Chaplin.js.

Has anybody used one or both frameworks and can say a little bit about them? Strengths, weaknesses, community behind it or are they basically the same?

This should not be a discussion about which is better, just a short feature list, so I can decide better which one to use, because I don't have the time to really get started with both.

Comment: http://9elements.com/io/index.php/comparison-of-marionette-and-chaplin/

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847852/what-are-the-real-world-strengths-and-weaknesses-of-the-many-frameworks-based-on

Answer (score 2):

Haven't worked with Marionette but basically Chaplin is a wise decision when:

- You need a more opinionated architecture. Useful if you need a set of rules/conventions to get up and running in a team.
- Memory management is a concern.
- You are maybe coming from a Ruby background and feel more comfortable using Coffeescript.

Also, if you are building a big application, in Chaplin get prepared to figure a LOT of things yourself. The documentation is [there](https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/tree/master/docs), but often you will find yourself 'alone in the dark'. Source is well commented though, which is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have experience with Marionette.js about 1 year.
Marionette.js is the best option when you have your own architecture, but you haven't ideas how working with views layer. 
I like the next scheme:

1. Backbone as core for data layer (models, collection, rest api)
2. Marionette.js for view layer (ItemView for one entity, CollectionView for collection of entities, CompositeView(entity + collection) and so on.
3. Reveal.js data binding
4. HBS as templates
5. Your own routing and core logic

I've recommended to you [brunch tool](http://brunch.io/) - is rich tool to compile, prepare and build your own SPA.
Of course you must see [Grunt + Yo + Bower](http://yeoman.io/) its another rich tool.